# JSDoc cannot parse config file SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jsdoc3

I am using JSDoc 3.4.3 and I'm trying to run config.json file to create documentation for multiple files. However every time I try to run the following command:

```
jsdoc -c conf.json
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot parse the config file conf.json: SyntaxError: Unexpected token : Exiting JSDoc because an error occurred. See the previous log messages for details.
```

I even tried copying and pasting the example config file found in official JSDoc documentation http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html

```
"source": {
"include": [ "myProject/a.js", "myProject/lib", "myProject/_private" ],
"exclude": [ "myProject/lib/ignore.js" ],
"includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc)?$",
"excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
}
```

But that gives the same error.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: How to fix? Copy the complete object from the "Configuration File" section

Comment: Thank you! It works! You should turn your comment into an answer so I can mark it as useful and as a solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. First, I verified that the file was encoded as UTF-8 via Notepad++. When that didn't work, based on the comment from Andreas, I simply copied and pasted my config code into the same file, saved, ran
`jsdoc -c jsdoc.conf` and it worked. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to feed it valid JSON, but in a file with `.js` extension. Silly mistake, I create a dynamic object and export it into a static json file before running JSDoc and forget to use `.json` extension for the created file. It gives `Cannot parse the config file [...].js: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` which is a really bad error message. Hope it helps someone.